# How to run psexec minimized from a VB script (VBS)

Tags: vbscript, psexec

When you do ...

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call WshShell.Run("psexec -u administrator -p pw1234 cmd /c ipconfig > C:\Output.txt", 2, True)
```

... you see for a short time the command prompt window.

I've been searching the web and I've tried everything I could possibly think of to hide/minimize this window, but unfortunately without success.

Is there really no way to run psexec in a hidden/minimized window?

PS: Unfortunately `Call WshShell.Run("psexec -u administrator -p pw1234 start /min cmd /c ipconfig > C:\Output.txt", 2, True)` doesn't work (error message: PsExec could not start start ...).

Comment: Did you tried something like that ? `Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "psexec cmd /c ipconfig /all > Output.txt",0,True`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But does this really solve the "problem" on your computer? I still see the command prompt window.
Since you've removed the authentication part ```-u administrator -p pw1234``` the command prompt window is now only visible for a very very short time, but it still appears. If you use the whole command ```WshShell.Run "psexec -u administrator -p pw1234 cmd /c ping 8.8.8.8 -n 5 > C:\Output.txt", 0, True``` the command prompt window is still visible for a longer time, isn't it?

Comment: Yep you are right ! i just tried right now and the issue is still there ! i'm sorry if i put you in a wrong direction !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there really no way to run `psexec` in a hidden/minimized window?

I believe `psexec` is running minimized. The command window that is being "flashed" is likely for `cmd /c`. `cmd /c` invokes a command window separately from whatever called it.

If you want to get around this "flash" effect, one method is to wrap the second command in VBScript as well. You may wish to try:

*ex. run_psexec.vbs*

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call WshShell.Run("psexec -u administrator -p pw1234 wscript C:\path\to\ip.vbs", 2, True)
```

*ex. ip.vbs*

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call WshShell.Run("cmd /c ipconfig > C:\ipconfig.txt", 2, True)
```

**Caveats**

- `C:\path\to\ip.vbs` probably shouldn't contain spaces. Perhaps this was an issue regarding testing, but I couldn't get additional double-quotes (`""`) to work correctly in the script above and single-quotes (`'`) are used for comments in VBScript.
- Using just ex. `ip.vbs` in conjunction with the `-u` and `-p` options to `psexec` caused `C:\Windows\System32` to be the default directory during script testing with my user on my machine. In any case, `wscript` should complain with a popup showing you where it's looking for a file if it can't find the script specified.

Comment: Great idea, and yes, it works perfectly!
I didn't think there would be solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note: If you do ```Call WshShell.Run("cmd /c ipconfig > ""C:\Output File.txt""", 0, True)```, it works even if the file name contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like that and it worked on my side !

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd psexec cmd /c (Ipconfig /all & Ping www.google.com) > output.txt",0,True
'MsgBox "Done",vbInformation,"Ping Results" 
WshShell.Run "output.txt"
```

Comment: At first sight it looked very promising, many thanks, but unfortunately your trick just disables the functionality of ```psexec```.
I need ```psexec``` so that a normal user can execute a command that requires administrative rights (e.g. ```WshShell.Run "psexec -u administrator -p pw1234 cmd /c netsh interface ip show address > C:\Output.txt", 2, True```).
In your proposed command ```WshShell.Run "cmd psexec -u administrator -p pw1234 cmd /c netsh interface ip show address > C:\Output.txt", 2, True``` it doesn't even matter if the password is correct or not because it's not checked at all.